# Spring Boot: Overriding CacheManager bean makes cache related properties not work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-cache

I have a Spring Boot 2 application with Redis cache. It worked just fine until I overridden `CacheManager` bean.

**Problem:** The following configuration property gets ignored (I can't turn off caching anymore):

```
spring.cache.type=none
```

Although [according to the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-caching.html#boot-features-caching-provider-none) it should work.

**Question:** How to make the `spring.cache.type=none` work?

There is a workaround [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46820604), but it is far from being a good solution.

**More details:** Here is how my configuration looks like:

```
@Configuration
public class CacheConfiguration {
    @Bean
    RedisCacheWriter redisCacheWriter(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return RedisCacheWriter.lockingRedisCacheWriter(connectionFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    CacheManager cacheManager(RedisCacheWriter redisCacheWriter) {
        Map<String, RedisCacheConfiguration> ttlConfiguration = ...
        RedisCacheConfiguration defaultTtlConfiguration = ...
        return new RedisCacheManager(
                redisCacheWriter, defaultTtlConfiguration, ttlConfiguration
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: With manually configuring the `CacheManager ` you disable the auto-configuration and thus the processing of the `spring.cache` annotations. If you want to use this property you will have to read and process it yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are creating the CacheManager yourself you also have to check `spring.cache.type` if you want to turn it of.

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnExpression("${spring.cache.type} != 'none'")
CacheManager cacheManager(RedisCacheWriter redisCacheWriter) {
```

Comment: I had to enclose `${spring.cache.type}` in single quotes (Using Spring 5 + Kotlin): `@ConditionalOnExpression("'${spring.cache.type}' != 'none'")`

Answer (score 1):

A Built in Spring Redis Cache configuration resides in `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.RedisCacheConfiguration`

It has a `@Conditional(CacheCondition.class)` on it.
This `CacheCondition` checks the value of `spring.cache.type` property. If its set to "NONE" the whole configuration, including the `RedisCacheManager` bean won't load at all.

Now as you've created your own configuration where you define the `cacheManager` by yourself it gets loaded regardless the value of `spring.cache.type` variable

So you should probably put some conditional value (that will read the `spring.cache.type` value or your custom condition)