# Conditionally auto-wire a bean implementation based on a value?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have an interface `Animal` having two implementations `Cat` and `Dog`. These two implementations are spring `@Component`. How do I conditionally wire these two based on a value? I understand that I may have to change the scope of MyTestController from singleton to request.

```
@RestController
public class MyTestController {

    @Autowired
    Animal animal;// how to wire bean of Cat or Dog based on animalName

    @PostMapping("/get-animal")
    public @ResponseBody Animal getAnimal(@RequestParam(value = "animalName") String animalName) {
        return animal;

    }

}
```

Comment: Are these implementation profile based or you will explicitly tell which one to use?

Comment: Don't Autowired. Just lookup the one you n eed inside your method

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we declare spring bean conditionally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39857804/can-we-declare-spring-bean-conditionally)

Comment: @MehrajMalik Not based on the profile.

Comment: I agree with M. Deinum, except I'd rather say: autowire them both, or autowire a List<Animal>, and lookup the one you need inside the method.

Answer (score 1):

Since both `MyTestController` is a bean the autowiring / initialisation happens **before** you actually start using the class instance itself. What I mean is that by the time you actually trigger REST requests on your controller, the injected `animal` bean should be already there!

More specifically if you have two classes that implement the same interface (`Animal`) without further specification (active Profiles, or `@Primary` annotation) Spring won't be able to decide which implementation to inject while creating the `MyTestController`,

What you want to do is return beans from your `ApplicationContext` based on a parameter / class name. This would look something like this:

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext context;

/* ... */
if(animalName.equals("dog") {
  context.getBean(Dog.class) //returning the dog bean
} else if(animalName.equals("cat") {
  context.getBean(Cat.class) //returning the cat bean
}
```

**Edit** IMO the question is a bit confusing. You ask for wiring the bean based on a value, but this value only comes at runtime. Hence my answer. However If you want to wire based on some variable at initialisation of your bean I would suggest taking a look at the following sources:

- [Profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html) - With profiles you can tell spring which instance to inject in which configuration. (E.g.: production/development/test configs and for each you want to inject different beans)
- [Primary](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-two-datasources) - One of your bean takes precedence over the others while injecting it.
- [Qualifier](https://spring.io/blog/2014/11/04/a-quality-qualifier)

Finally I would note that such an inversion on the IoC is considered as a bad practice. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812415/why-is-springs-applicationcontext-getbean-considered-bad))

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're missing the whole point. Don't autowire simple DTO, but autowire AnimalFactory or some kind of AnimalRepository (or better - Service) where you can create or retrieve animals based on animal type.

It would look something like that:

```
@Component
public class AnimalFactory {

  public Animal createAnimal(String animalType) {
     switch (animalType) {
       case "DOG":
        return new Dog();
       case "CAT":
        return new Cat();
     }
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("AnimalType is invalid");
  }

}
```

Animal Spring Data JPA Repository:

```
@Component
public class AnimalRepository implements JpaRepository<Animal, Long> {

  public Optional<Animal> findByAnimalName(String animalName);

}
```