# How to get command line argument inside BeanFactoryPostProcessor?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I am using Spring boot for my application written on Kotlin. I am able to get command line arguments using `Environment.getProperty("nonOptionArgs", Array<String>::class.java)`

However, inside `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` i cannot autowire environment - as this post-processor is running too early in the lifecycle. How I can access command line arguments inside `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`?

Comment: @ Lino you are right  - this is Kotlin : )

Comment: Try to autowire `org.springframework.boot.ApplicationArguments` and then call its method `getSourceArgs`. See if this works.

Comment: @VHS  does not work - when `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` is running - there are no beans at all in context - only bean definition.

Comment: why you need to get command line args in BeanFactoryPostProcessor ?

Comment: @Abdelghani Roussi, i would like to define dynamically beans based on command argument values. Why to i do this in `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` - is to be sure that bean definitions are there before actual bean instantiation- so i don't need `@DependsOn` annotation.

Comment: If there are discreet number of cases based on your command line args, you can try to use [ConditionalOnProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39858222/5749570).

Comment: @OleksandrPapchenko in term of loading beans conditionally (like auto-configuration in spring boot), I would say that it's much cleaner to use the `@ConditionalXXX` annotations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well , you can implement your `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` with `EnvironmentAware` to get the `Environment` :

```
@Component
public class FooBeanFactoryPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor , EnvironmentAware{

    private Environment env;

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {

            env.getProperty("nonOptionArgs");
            //I should be able to access env at here .Hehe

    }

    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
            this.env = environment;
    }

}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you, this actually works! This is amazing.  As i understand there is still no Environment bean defined on the context - at the time of `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` there are no beans at all - however, spring creates Environment really early in lifecycle ?

Comment: Yeah, it creates `Environment` at the constructor when creating the context . My guess is that it will create  `Environment` first but later register this instance as a bean .So technically , the `Environment` set into `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` is still not a spring bean yet but it will eventually be a spring bean.. My guess...

Answer (score 1):

From your comment :

> I would like to define dynamically beans based on command argument
>   values. Why to i do this in BeanFactoryPostProcessor - is to be sure
>   that bean definitions are there before actual bean instantiation- so i
>   don't need @DependsOn annotation.

In term of loading beans conditionally (like auto-configuration in spring boot), I would say that it's much cleaner to use the **@ConditionalXXX** annotations, most specifically the **@ConditionalOnProperty**.

Referencing the Java-doc for `@ConditionalOnProperty` [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnProperty.html) they said :

> Conditional that checks if the specified properties have a specific
>   value. By default the properties must be present in the Environment
>   and not equal to false. The havingValue() and matchIfMissing()
>   attributes allow further customizations.

So you can do something similar to :

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "my.env", name = "var", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = false)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, however, i would like to define a dynamic number of beans based on command line arguments.