# creating schema with CommandLineRunner spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

In my Spring Boot application, I'm using CommandLineRunner to create a new schema and them import some test data after that.

```
@Profile("create-schema")
@Component
public class CreateSchema {
    // creating schema inside. This works because I can see from the database
}

@Profile("import-data")
@Component
public class DataImporter {
}
```

and this is the sequence in application.properties

```
spring.profiles.active=${SPRING_PROFILE}, create-schema, import-data
```

And using this in application.properties

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=simba
```

Schema creation starts after the application has started; and after schema is created, import-data starts.

when import-data is running, I get an error that

> relation `schema_name.table_name` does not exist

However, once the schema is created and I run the application again - it works. So, when I have to deploy my app where every time I have to create a schema to run some integration tests - it would fail there.

am I running something in wrong order?

Comment: why do use profiles here?

Comment: no specific reason, I was following an article for CommandLineRunner and saw there. Is that an issue?\

Comment: @AndrewTobilko one of the reasons mentioned there was - to separate the command line runner on different environments. on production, you may not want to import-data.

Comment: Also, why use Spring for that and not use a tool built for the job: https://flywaydb.org/

Comment: @SofoGial is it not possible to do via Spring?

Comment: It totally is, but it's not the easiest way :)

Comment: @nirvair I just feel like you are misusing them. You could make these beans conditional based on another application property. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39857804/can-we-declare-spring-bean-conditionally

Comment: @AndrewTobilko But, even if I do that - the command line runner will behave the same way, right?

Comment: @nirvair I don't know if a `CommandLineRunner` is the right place to do such things. First, make sure the order of beans is the same as you are expecting.  Can `DataImporter` be executed before `CreateSchema`?

Comment: No, schema is created first and then DataImporter is executed.

Answer (score 1):

Profiles are completely irrelevant here. You can ensure the schema is created before the data import by doing something like the following:

```
@Component("schemaCreator")
public class SchemaCreator {

    @PostConstruct
    public void initSchema(){

    }
}
```

Data Importer can be made dependent on the schema being initialised via the `@DependsOn` annotation.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/DependsOn.html

> Beans on which the current bean depends. Any beans specified are
>   guaranteed to be created by the container before this bean. Used
>   infrequently in cases where a bean does not explicitly depend on
>   another through properties or constructor arguments, but rather
>   depends on the side effects of another bean's initialization.

```
@DependsOn("schemaCreator")
@Component
public class DataImporter {

    @PostConstruct
    public void initData(){

    }
}
```