# How to create @Controller and @Service instance conditionally on Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, javabeans

I am using Spring Boot 1.5.9.

Is there a way to turn on/off `@Controller` and `@Services`?

Something such as `@ConditionalOnProperty`, `@Conditional` for beans.

```java
@ConditionalController // <--- something like this
@RestController
public class PingController {

    @Value("${version}")
    private String version;

    @RequestMapping(value = CoreHttpPathStore.PING, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> ping() throws Exception {
        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("message", "Welcome to our API");
        map.put("date", new Date());
        map.put("version", version);
        map.put("status", HttpStatus.OK);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(map, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

Then use some configuration bean to load it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@ConditionalOnProperty` should work for Controller (or Service) as well, since it is also a Spring bean.

Add to your PingController

```java
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix="ping.controller",
        name="enabled",
        havingValue="true")
@RestController
public class PingController {...}
```

and to the application.properties to turn it on/off

```
ping.controller.enabled=false
```

Comment: Thanks, I am using `@ConditionalOnExpression("${features.core.ping:true}")` and it also work. Thanks !

Comment: Exactly, as Controller and Service are just another Spring beans you simply follow the approaches already described at many SO pages, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39857804/can-we-declare-spring-bean-conditionally.

Comment: Also take a look at Spring profiles: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles, it's much older than @Conditional, but for most usecases, it works equally and is less verbose.

Answer (score 0):

do you want to try and load the bean programmatically instead?

you could access the application context using one of the two mechanisms

> @Autowired private ApplicationContext appContext;

or creating something like a bean factory by extending ApplicationAware

> public class ApplicationContextProvider implements
>   ApplicationContextAware{

once you have a handle to the application context you can add a bean to the context programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

By default in Spring, all the defined beans, and their dependencies, are created when the application context is created.

We can turn it off by configuring a bean with lazy initialization, the bean will only be created, and its dependencies injected, once they're needed.

You can enable lazy initialization by configuring `application.properties`.

```
spring.main.lazy-initialization=true
```

Setting the property value to true means that all the beans in the application will use lazy initialization.

All the defined beans will use lazy initialization, except for those that we explicitly configure with `@Lazy(false)`.

Or you can do it through the `@Lazy` approach. When we put `@Lazy` annotation over the `@Configuration` class, it indicates that all the methods with `@Bean` annotation should be loaded lazily.

```
@Lazy
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.app.lazy")
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public Region getRegion(){
        return new Region();
    }

    @Bean
    public Country getCountry(){
        return new Country();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't always force Spring not to create a bean only just by marking it as lazy. Using `@Conditional...` or Spring profiles is the way to go...