# Spring, configure preferred bean to autowire when multiple instances are present

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

I've an interface being injected as bean into multiple components.
Three classes implement this interface which leads to ambiguity for spring to autowire the beans.

I would like a flexible way (preferentially through the application.properties or an env var) to specify which bean to chose...

EX

```
public interface MyComponent{
}
@Component("a")
public class MyComponentA implements MyComponent{
}
@Component("b")
public class MyComponentB implements MyComponent {
}

@Component("c")
public class MyComponentC implements MyComponent{
}
```

then many classes through the system might autowire this component

```
@Autowired
MyComponent bean;
```

I know i can use `@Qualifier("a")` to determine which implementation to inject, but the problem is that if I want to cheange from 'a' to 'c' i will need to change the code in multiple places...

I wanted a global way to select which bean to use when qualifier is not present

Comment: like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39857804/can-we-declare-spring-bean-conditionally)?

Comment: Look at  [‘@Primary‘](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html) annotation

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are looking for is the @ConditionalOnProperty annotation that you can apply to the component:

```
@Component("a")
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "component", havingValue = "a")
public class MyComponentA implements MyComponent{
}

@Component("b")
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "component", havingValue = "b")
public class MyComponentB implements MyComponent {
}

@Component("c")
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "component", havingValue = "c")
public class MyComponentC implements MyComponent{
}
```

See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-conditionalonproperty for more information about this solution.

You can explore more about conditional annotations in Spring here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-conditional-annotations